# How to change the name field of an <input> in an AJAX-driven page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, userscripts, tampermonkey

For this target page (Sorry but SO doesn't allow hyperlinks to 62.0.54.118):

```
http://62.0.54.118/search?&q=42&oq=42&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&filter=0
```

, I want to change the name field of an `<input>` by default with a userscript.

The input is:

```
<input class="gsfi" id="lst-ib" name="q" maxlength="2048" value="42"...>
```

I want to change it to:

```
<input class="gsfi" id="lst-ib" name="&q" maxlength="2048" value="42"...>
```

That is, I Want to change the `q` into `&q` in the `name` field of the input by default.

I try to write a script, (that doesn't work):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Normal Google Input
// @include  http://62.0.54.118/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
waitForKeyElements ("input[name*='q']", changeLinkQuery);

function changeLinkQuery (jNode) {
    var oldName = jNode.attr ('name');
    var newName = oldName.replace (/\q/, "&q");

    jNode.attr ('name', newName);

    return true;
}
```

In addition, the page is an Ajax-driven page.

Please fix my bad script or help me to write another one,
Thanks.

**Update:**
I solved a part of that by changing a line of my script from:

```
var newName = oldName.replace (/\q/, "&q");
```

to

```
var newName = oldName.replace (/q/, "&q");
```

and then my script works better. Thanks to @Gerard Sexton for suggesting that.

But there is a new bug now,  with the `waitForKeyElements` callback set to `return true;` for the page's AJAX,  It adds the `&` non stop.

It causes this field to be `name="&&&&&&&&&q"`, etc.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Change your regex to /q/

Comment: thanks, its do the trick

Comment: i did it but i still have a bug with the script:
the `return true;`, for the ajax make the `&` to add with non stop what cause this field to be `name="&&&&&&&&&q"`

Comment: "static Ajax-driven page" is a bit of an oxymoron.  Generally, if a page has any significant content that is AJAX-driven, the page is considered AJAX-driven, even though it may have static elements.

Comment: @reemar it sounds like the changeLinkQuery function is being called many times. Maybe waitForKeyElements invokes the callback for EVERY element that matches the selector.

Comment: it was related to the waitForKeyElements but Bruck Adams solve the problem, V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input name is just `q`, by itself, then merely change the waitForKeyElements call to:

```
waitForKeyElements ("input[name='q']", changeLinkQuery);
```

So that it looks for *exactly* `q`, rather than a q anywhere in the string.

---

If that's not *exactly* the name of that `<input>`, comment below.