# How can I combine two userscripts into one?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, userscripts

I wrote two scripts that are really similar, and I want them both to work together under one script, how can I do it?

The First:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Normal Google
// @include  http://62.0.54.118/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
waitForKeyElements ("a[href*='?q=']", changeLinkQuery);

function changeLinkQuery (jNode) {
    var oldHref = jNode.attr ('href');
    var newHref = oldHref.replace (/\?q=/, "?&q=");

    jNode.attr ('href', newHref);

    return true;
}
```

The Second userscript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Normal Google Input
// @include  http://62.0.54.118/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
waitForKeyElements ("input[name*='q']", changeLinkQuery);

function changeLinkQuery (jNode) {
    var oldName = jNode.attr ('name');
    var newName = oldName.replace (/q/, "&q");

    jNode.attr ('name', newName);

    return true;
}
```

How can I combine those userscripts together?

---

This is a **bad** solution that I try to write that **does not work**.

What am I doing wrong?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Google
// @include  http://62.0.54.118/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
waitForKeyElements ("a[href*='?q=']","input[name*='q']", changeLinkQuery);

function changeLinkQuery (j1,j2) {
    var oldHref = j1.attr ('href');
    var newHref = oldHref.replace (/\?q=/, "?&q=");
    var oldName = j2.attr ('name');
    var newName = oldName.replace (/q/, "&q");

    j1.attr ('href', newHref);
    j2.attr ('name', newName);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Personally I think the two scripts are different enough to keep them separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two scripts both have a function named `changeLinkQuery`, but `changeLinkQuery` is not the same in each!   Plus one of the `changeLinkQuery` functions is misnamed, because it is not changing any link's query part.

Also, `waitForKeyElements` does not take multiple selector strings like that, but a jQuery selector can have multiple parts.

So this is bad: `"a[href*='?q=']","input[name*='q']"`

But this will work: `"a[href*='?q='],input[name*='q']"` but is not the best way for your situation.

The solution is to rename one of the `changeLinkQuery` functions, like so (also incorporating [the fix from your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19416772/331508)):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Normal Google Input
// @include  http://62.0.54.118/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
waitForKeyElements ("a[href*='?q=']",  changeLinkQuery);
waitForKeyElements ("input[name='q']", changeInputName);

function changeLinkQuery (jNode) {
    var oldHref = jNode.attr ('href');
    var newHref = oldHref.replace (/\?q=/, "?&q=");

    jNode.attr ('href', newHref);
    return true;
}

function changeInputName (jNode) {
    var oldName = jNode.attr ('name');
    var newName = oldName.replace (/q/, "&q");

    jNode.attr ('name', newName);
    return true;
}
```